# How to set TileView (GridView) in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview

I've been bothering with the problem of replicating `GridView` or `TileView` (doesn't really matter how you will call it) in WPF `ListView` component for some time and found some very complicated and confusing answers. Not all of them worked, and some of them didn't work with custom databinding with templates. Couldn't find a straightforward, simple answer on SO as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simpliest method I've came up with:

```
<ListView ItemTemplate="{...}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Please enjoy.